# Read an input that is separated by spaces, parenthesis, and commas with scanf() and fgets()

Tags: c, input, scanf, fgets

I have the following input:

```
1 (2 ,3 ,4) lantern
```

The number of int inputs between the parenthesis is unknown, and could extend for a while.

My original thought was to scanf() the first int, then create a while loop to determine when the closed paranethsis is scanned. Then finally use fgets() to get the string at the end, something similar to this.

```
scanf("%d", &address);  //first input

scanf("%c", &paren);    //scan the '(' or ',' or ')'

int current_room = 0;   //index for array inside parenthsis

while(paren == '(' || paren == ','){

    scanf("%d,", adjoined_room[current_room]);  //scan am int

    scanf("%c", &paren);   //scan a ',' or ')'

    current_room++;        //increase the index

}
```

This however prints the following output when I print my address, array, and string:

```
Address: 1
Item: (2 ,3 ,4) lantern
```

The inputted ints between the parenthesis were never set to the array. Is there a better way to determine when ')' is inputted?

Comment: Note that mixing `fgets` and `scanf` is never a good idea. You're much better off just reading the whole line with `fgets`. Then you can decide how to best parse the line. `strtol`, `strchr`, and `strtok` are standard library functions that you may find useful.

Comment: The issue I am finding is that the data between the parenthesis can go on for quite a while, unsure of the amount of inputs. So I don't think getting the entire line itself would work out. I'm using malloc to allocate all my data while I get the int. Is there anyway to stop scanf for ints instead of parse the whole line?

Comment: Don't do this with `scanf()`. Use `strtok()` to parse the line.

Comment: Define *"quite a while"*. Are we talking 100's, 1000's, or millions of numbers. One of the common mistakes that new C programmers make is to be too stingy with memory. The result is horribly convoluted code, as demonstrated by William's answer.

Comment: Less than the max values of unsigned long.

Comment: @thatsquitemid What is the array size of `adjoined_room[]`?

Comment: @user3386109 "Horribly convoluted"!?

Comment: @WilliamPursell As compared to Chris Dodd's simple straightforward code for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf("%c",` will read the very next character in the input, without skipping any whitespace.  If you want to skip whitespace, you need a space in the format, eg `scanf(" %c",`.  You should also check the scanf return value to make sure that you got an integer

Adding that to your code gives you something like:

```
if (scanf("%d", &address) != 1) {  //first input
    fprintf(stderr, "syntax error\n");
    return;  // not an integer -- do something else
}
scanf(" %c", &paren);    //scan the '(' or ',' or ')'
int current_room = 0;   //index for array inside parenthsis
while(paren == '(' || paren == ','){
    if (scanf("%d", adjoined_room[current_room]) == 1) {  //scan an int
        current_room++;        //increase the index
    }
    scanf(" %c", &paren);   //scan a ',' or ')'
    if (paren != ',' && paren != ')') {
        fprintf(stderr, "syntax error\m");
        return;
    }
}
```

If you want to do this with interactive input, you should probably use `fgets` or `getline` to read entire lines and `sscanf` to parse each line independently so you don't confuse your user when there's an error in the middle of a line.  The "read line + sscanf" is also very useful if you have a number of different patterns that you want to try (sscanf on the same line with different formats to find the first one that matches).

Comment: I just tried out using scanf(" %c", ..) and it just might seem to work. Have to tweak a few things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` should never be used.  Ever.  But....you might try something like:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz);

int
main(void)
{
        size_t cap = 4;
        char buf[1024];
        int *x = xrealloc(NULL, cap, sizeof *x);
        if( scanf("%d ( %d", x, x + 1) != 2 ){
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Ivalid input");
        }
        int *y = x + 2;
        while( scanf(",%d", y) == 1 ){
                if( ++y == x + cap ){
                        cap += 4;
                        x = xrealloc(x, cap, sizeof *x);
                }
        }
        if( scanf(")%1023s", buf) != 1 ){
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Ivalid input");
        }
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < y - x; i += 1 ){
                printf("x[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        return 0;
}
void *
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz)
{
        char *b = buf;
        b = realloc(b, num * siz);
        if( b == NULL ){
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return b;
}
```

This does not correctly handle input with a trailing comma like: `1 (2 ,3 ,4, ) lantern`, and I'm sure there are many other inputs that it does not like.  Exercise left for the reader.

You probably don't want to use an initial capacity as small as 4, but it's convenient for simple testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this might help with my allocation with the data between the parenthesis, as an array might not be able to hold all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most popular answer, and it may or may not help your immediate goals, but I am of the philosophy to read input as a stream of bytes and parse via (crude or sophisticated) state machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define process_word(x) (printf("Got string \'%s\'\n", x))
#define process_number(x) (printf("Got number %lu\n", strtoul(x, NULL, 10)))

int main(void) {
        int c;
        int depth = 0;
        size_t i;
        char digitbuffer[256];
        char alphabuffer[256];

        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
                switch (c) {
                case ' ': 
                case ',':
                        break;
                case '(': 
                        depth++;
                        break;
                case ')':
                        if (depth == 0) perror("Mismatched parenthesis, skipping");
                        else depth--;
                        break;
                default:
                        if (isalpha(c)) {
                                memset(alphabuffer, 0, 256);
                                alphabuffer[0] = c;
                                i = 1;
                                while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF &&
                                    isalpha(c) &&
                                    i < 255) {
                                        alphabuffer[i++] = c;
                                }
                                if (!isalpha(c) && c != EOF) ungetc(c, stdin);
                                process_word(alphabuffer);
                        }
                        else if (isdigit(c)) {
                                memset(digitbuffer, 0, 256);
                                digitbuffer[0] = c;
                                i = 1;
                                while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF &&
                                    isdigit(c) &&
                                    i < 255) {
                                        digitbuffer[i++] = c;
                                }
                                if (!isdigit(c) && c != EOF) ungetc(c, stdin);
                                process_number(digitbuffer);
                        }
                        break;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This gives you the most control over handling your specific data format, in my opinion.

You can define your own `process_word()` and `process_number()` functions, of course.  `process_number()` might assign the number to the `address` field of a record if `depth == 0`, for example, or add it to `adjacent_room[]` if `depth == 1`. `process_word()` might add the string to the `item` field of the same record.  Completely up to you.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯